# After uninstall app creating new user insted of get userID from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have app which during launch create anonymous user ID, but after **uninstall** my app create new user with new ID. How can I get **userID** which was before **uninstall** ?

My code to anonymous login:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    
    
            if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
                createUser();
            }else{
                user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            }

  }

 public void createUser() {


        mAuth.signInAnonymously().addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.d("TAG", "signIn: succes");
                }else{
                    Log.w("TAG", "signIn: fail");
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Firebase Authentication to create and use only temporary anonymous accounts to authenticate with Firebase. `Anonymous authentication` accounts don't persist across application uninstalls. When an application is uninstalled, everything that was saved locally will be deleted, including the anonymous auth token that identifies that account. **Unfortunatelly, there is no easy way to reclaim that token for the user**.

Instead, you should encourage all your users to fully log in with a supported account provider (`Google`, `Fabcebook`, `Twitter` and so on) so that they can log in from all their devices without worry of losing their data.

Comment: Thanks, so I will take user device ID from my app and put to database insted of using Firebase auth

Comment: It's another approach but i recomand you implementing Firebase authentication.

Comment: Yeah, but my app need anonymous login, so take device ID is best idea I think. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Store id in SharedPreferences before app uninstall.

Comment: Okey, but anonumous auth is connected to device ID, so why it dosent check if deviceID is in database and take the id ?

Comment: But SharedPreferences data are also deleted when app is uninstalled.