# Are the authenticated security rules applicable for Firebase Anonymous sign-in?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to develop an app where I do not want my users to sign-in by their avatar names and not any account such as Google or Facebook with proper security. Is it really possible? I mean, are all the security rules applicable for those who have signed in anonymously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the authenticated security rules applicable for Firebase Anonymous sign-in?

Of course, they are. According to the official documentation regarding [Firebase Anonymous Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth):

> You can use Firebase Authentication to create and use temporary anonymous accounts to authenticate with Firebase. These temporary anonymous accounts can be used to allow users who haven't yet signed up to your app to work with **data protected by security rules**.

And to answer your last question:

> I mean, are all the security rules apply for those who have signed in anonymously?

Yes, the security rules are applicable for an anonymous account, in the same manner, are applicable for an account that is created with a provider such as Google, Facebook, and so on.

Comment: Alex, please tell me something. If Anonymous authentication gives all the necessary authentication securities like the others (such as Google, Facebook etc.), then what is the difference between Anonymous authentication and other authentication  processes (except syncing data over multiple devices)?

Comment: Syncing data over multiple devices is one of the best benefits. Besides that, if you are using a provider, you can get multiple information of the user, like name, email address, profile picture URL, and so on. Moreover, you'll never lose data. If you uninstall the app, [you can **not** reclaim the token for the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47136603/after-uninstall-app-creating-new-user-insted-of-get-userid-from-firebase).

Comment: So, to conclude, we can say that Anonymous authentication has no disadvantage with respect to security rules, compared to other authentication processes. Am I right, Alex?